# I'm unable to read any book or write a single line

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, readers, career, inspiration

So, there was a time when I could finish a book in 2 days. All I did was read books and sometimes I took some time out to write something as well.

For the past few months though? Nothing. When I sit to read, I can't finish a single page even if my life depended on it.

And writing? I mean I chose to make a career out of writing, but now only blank word documents are saved in my laptop. Zero inspiration with no more day dreaming and no more story ideas running through my mind.

Today I read a post on Tumblr, where someone posted something similar and also mentioned that it's all because of depression. I've been feeling low for a while, but I need to get back to my job, my career and my dream. Staring at a blank document just makes me feel more sad and depressed. I've been trying to change the way I think but nothing is really working and nothing is making sense anymore. If you're reading this and have gone through something similar please help me out here.

Should I consider changing my career path? How can I go back to being creative again? Have I lost my creativity?

Thanks in advance:)

P.S: It took me  2 hours to write this description. Lol

Comment: Have you looked into diagnosis and/or treatment for your depression?

Comment: What are you doing with your time instead?  Watching YouTube videos?  Scrolling through comments?  Playing video games?  Literally staring at the wall?  Lying in bed in a darkened room?  The appropriate advice for someone who can't stay off Facebook long enough to get things done is going to be different than the advice for someone who is curled in a corner crying for several hours every day.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I've been spending my time, binge watching Youtube videos and aimlessly scrolling through Pinterest and Tumblr in hopes of getting rid of voices in my head telling me that 'writing is just not for me' and in the hopes of being inspired by something and that something pushing me to WRITE something. Anything.

Comment: I don't cry but I do feel lonely and lost. This is not my first experience with depression withno activity, I've dealt with it in the past too and somehow managed to get out of it. But this time it seems like I've exhausted all possibilities and this is it. The worst part? I keep expecting that somehow everything will go back to 'normal' and tomorrow will be better. (Sorry for venting out so much)

Comment: some people trick themselves into writing. Things like rolling dice to see what happens next and just write down what the dice say. Or taking a character from a story you know (or a TV show) and writing something about how they would do something unexpected like host a cooking show. These writings are not for keeping, they're for getting going. Does something like that appeal at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced something very similar, in fact I still have it. But I have gotten to the point where I can read again and/or write. I just still have depression.

It's hard, but if it goes on long enough, it will either get worse or get better. What I would suggest, though, is maybe not try to defeat your depression, but find a way around it. That's what I did. What I found that helps is taking walks (now I'm addicted to walks), eating healthier (just foods and meals that are better for you, little to no fast food, etc.), and just trying to do something.

Don't abandon your dream and career. Take this time and try to get better, then learn from it. You could use this time as an idea or a part of a character in your future books. But what you need to do is focus on finding a way around it, underneath it, above it, or through it. You might even have to find another path. But if you try, you're more likely to win.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, thanks and thanks a lot! Initially I thought that this is happening to me because ..well because I deserve it. Good to know, that there's someone out there who knows how I feel and has managed to get around it. I'll work on your tips. Thanks again!:)

Comment: @user37485 No problem. It sucks (I would know), but if you let this win, you've lost. But if you fight back, you're winning. Just keep in mind that destiny isn't real. Things happen, but they were never "fate." You carve your own fate. And things happen, but if you make the best of a situation, it's bound to get better. Good luck. Hope you get better!

Answer (score 3):

I've suffered something similar, though not exactly same situation.

My suggestion is that you make a simple excel sheet and daily record how many words you wrote and how many pages you read that day. Add a row every day. It doesn't matter if you only read few sentences or your mind wasn't concentrated during reading time. Just record the numbers and make a graph of them. It helps you to get a perspective.

Rest you can only depend on yourself.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Your suggestion to create an excel sheet, and record the number of pages I've read and the words I've written in a day is really helpful! It'll surely give me a perspective and a much needed push to get better. Actually, since my days are mostly unproductive, I've decided to record my activities (since today) (& whatever little I do), in a notebook and take a look at it at the end of the day. Is that ok? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yup. I prefer excel as I like to see data visually, like graphs etc. You can do it in your preferred way. Just keep consistency.